# How to compare two array and push data based on result Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

**I have add my all code below, but important function is patchDataCollection() where i have added push logic for forms.**

I want to compare values of both arrayOne and arrayTwo based on below condition and if it matches than it will pass data along with form otherwise it will create an empty form.

**Expected output**
I have created patchDataCollection() function where i am creating forms based on above condition, but in my case it is patching data to all generated forms
, i want only patch thosa object which are avlbl in arrayTww.

**Below condition i wanted to check in arrayOne and arrayTwo.**

1. if arrayOne processTypeId is equal to arrayTwo of makeProcessTypeId And
2. arrayOne makeLineName is equal to arrayTwo of makeLineName And
3. arrayOne processTechType is equal to arrayTwo of processTechType than

If all above conditions are met than only **dataOne** variable will pass along with form.

```
 this.itemTypes().push(this.createContinuousForm(item, dataOne));
```

else it will create an empty form only without pushing dataOne in form.

```
 this.itemTypes().push(this.createContinuousForm(item)); 

     

Const arrayOne = [
      {
        "makeLineName": "Red",
        types : [
            {
                "processTypeId": 101,
                "processTechType": "Batch" 
            },
             {
                "processTypeId": 102,
                "processTechType": "Batch" 
            }
        ]   
      },
      {
        "makeLineName": "Blue",
        types : [
            {
                "processTypeId": 103,
                "processTechType": "Continuous" 
            },
            {
                "processTypeId": 104,
                "processTechType": "Batch" 
            }
        ]     
      } 
    ];

    Const arrayTwo = 
    [
      {   
        "makeProcessTypeId": 101,
        "makeLineName": "Red",
        "processTechType": "Batch",
        "avgBct": 23,
        "bestBct": 23
      },
      {   
        "makeProcessTypeId": 102,
        "makeLineName": "Blue",
        "processTechType": "Batch",
        "avgBct": 45,
        "bestBct": 45
      },
      {   
        "makeProcessTypeId": 103,
        "makeLineName": "Blue",
        "processTechType": "Continuous",
        "designProcessCapacity": 250,
        "minRunLength": 250
      }
    ];   

   

  getMakeLineData() { 
        for (const line of arrayOne) {
          const list = line.types;
          for (const item of list) {
            if (item.processTechType === 'Continuous') {
              this.patchDataCollection(item);
            } else if (item.processTechType === 'Batch' || item.processTechType === 'Batch-Crunch') {
              this.patchDataCollection(item);
            }
          }
        }   
  }

  patchDataCollection(arrayOne) {
      if (arrayTwo) {
        for (const dataOne of arrayTwo) {
          if (arrayOne.makeLineName == dataOne.makeLineName) {
            if (arrayOne.processTechType === 'Continuous') {
              this.itemTypes().push(this.createContinuousForm(item, dataOne));
            }
            if (dataOne.processTechType === 'Batch' || dataOne.processTechType === 'Batch-Crunch') {
              this.itemTypes().push(this.createBatchForm(item, dataOne));
            }           
          }
        }
      } 
  }


createContinuousForm(type, data) {
    return this.fb.group({     
      makeLineName: [type.makeLineName],     
      processTechType: [type.processTechType],
      makeProcessTypeId: [type.processTypeId],
      designProcessCapacity: [data.designProcessCapacity ? data.designProcessCapacity : '', [Validators.required]],
      minRunLength: [data.minRunLength ? data.minRunLength : '']     
    });
  }

  createBatchForm(type, data) {
    return this.fb.group({     
      makeLineName: [type.makeLineName],      
      processTechType: [type.processTechType],
      makeProcessTypeId: [type.processTypeId],
      avgBct: [data.avgBct ? data.avgBct : '', [Validators.required]],
      bestBct: [data.bestBct ? data.bestBct : '', [Validators.required]]     
    });
  }

  itemTypes(): FormArray {
    return this.dataCollectionForm.get("items") as FormArray;
  }
```

Comment: Where does the `item` in `patchDataCollection` come from? The variable isn't declared somewhere

Comment: Is the structure of the arrays in your hands?

Comment: The `item` you pass to `patchDataCollection` has the structure `{ processTypeId: string; processTechType: string; }` it won't have any `makeLineName` for you to access and compare within the function!

Comment: Please make sure you post a reproducible exampe. Your code is not runnable as is. Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sthuber90/3h9uyL4x/1/) where I added your code. I you open the development console in your browser, you can see that you are not passing an object with the property `makeLineName`

Comment: @st.huber, Working demo with full code..  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xr5bcg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

While I think there are better ways to store the data compared to what the API returns to you, it is certainly possible to compare the two arrays and only use the values that exist in both arrays, given your conditions.

The surrounding object with `makeLineName` and `types` in your `arrayOne` do not contain any valuable information (any information that is not within the `types` array anyway). You can start here with:

```typescript
arrayOne.flatMap(i => i.types)
```

From my perspective the `createContinuousForm` and `createBatchForm` functions don't need two parameters. It should be enough if you pass the item from `arrayTwo` as the only values from `arrayOne` used in your functions are the one that must match the ones from `arrayTwo`.

I could see something in this direction working:

```js
const arrayOne = [{
    makeLineName: 'Red',
    types: [{
      processTypeId: '102',
      processTechType: 'Batch',
      makeLineName: 'Red',
    }, ],
  },
  {
    makeLineName: 'Blue',
    types: [{
      processTypeId: '103',
      processTechType: 'Continuous',
      makeLineName: 'Blue',
    }, ],
  },
];

const arrayTwo = [{
    makeProcessTypeId: 101,
    makeLineName: 'Red',
    processTechType: 'Batch',
    avgBct: 23,
    bestBct: 23,
  },
  {
    makeProcessTypeId: 102,
    makeLineName: 'Blue',
    processTechType: 'Batch',
    avgBct: 45,
    bestBct: 45,
  },
  {
    makeProcessTypeId: 103,
    makeLineName: 'Blue',
    processTechType: 'Continuous',
    designProcessCapacity: 250,
    minRunLength: 250,
  },
];

const simplifiedArrayOne = arrayOne.flatMap(i => i.types);

function createContinuousForm(item) {
  console.log({
    // if you put this into [], then your makeLineName is an array with one value
    makeLineName: item.makeLineName,
    processTechType: item.processTechType,
    makeProcessTypeId: item.makeProcessTypeId,
    designProcessCapacity: [
      item.designProcessCapacity ? item.designProcessCapacity : ''
    ],
  });
}

function createBatchForm(item) {
  console.log({
    makeLineName: item.makeLineName,
    processTechType: item.processTechType,
    makeProcessTypeId: item.makeProcessTypeId,
    avgBct: item.avgBct ? item.avgBct : '',
    bestBct: item.bestBct ? item.bestBct : '',
  });
}

arrayTwo.filter(entry => {
  // .toString() is necessary because your types of processTypeId (string) and makeProcessTypeId (number) are different
  const index = simplifiedArrayOne.findIndex(e => e.processTypeId === entry.makeProcessTypeId.toString())
  return index > -1 && entry.makeLineName === simplifiedArrayOne[index].makeLineName
}).forEach(item => item.processTechType === 'Continuous' ? this.createContinuousForm(item) : this.createBatchForm(item));
```

Please take note of the comments within the code. Also, as you're using TypeScript you could use an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) for the `processTechType` and possibly another one for the `makeLineName` as well

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. let me check its working as expected or not. Also i have created one stackblitz demo with code, What i need is if values present in both arrayone and arrayTwo then arraytwo value should patch in the form, whatever the form type is and if value of arrayone not present in arrayTwo, Then empty form will appear.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xr5bcg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I believe my answer provides what you're looking for. Take your time to look into it and check if it works for you. I've seen your stackblitz. Thank you very much for it. If my answer helps you, it would be kind if you upvote or mark it as accepted answer if it solves your problem fully

Comment: No worry even if your answer not worked fully for me, then also i will upvote your answer, bcz u make efforts to fix issue. So thank you so much.